# Combinatorics in a dynamic system?

Tags: combinatorics

On page 44 of his article "An Imitation of Life," William Grey Walter claims that "six elements would be more than enough to form a system which would provide a new pattern every tenth of a second for 280 years." What mathematics support this claim? I am only aware of straightforward combinatorics, which states that 6 objects can make 720 unique combinations. How does Walter claim so many more?

https://cse-robotics.engr.tamu.edu/dshell/cs643/papers/walter50imitation.pdf

Thanks!

Kelly

Comment: 6 objects can make 64 combinations and 720 permutations to be mathematically exact :), 7 lines above author also defines relations between chosen states, each pair in configuration having one of 4 relations contribute to number of configurations I am unaware how these relations work so I can't compute exact number, but stating problem on stackexchange someone will give you an answer

Comment: It's not at all clear (to me) what Walter is talking about, but I would suggest trying to understand what he means when he says that two elements can exist in any of six "modes" (or "dynamic forms"), $A$, $B$, $A+B$, $A\rightharpoonup B$, $B\rightharpoonup A$, and $A\rightleftharpoons B$.

Comment: @barrycipra yes, exactly -- I was hoping someone here would understand his use of those symbols.

Comment: For what it's worth, $$280\cdot365\cdot24\cdot60\cdot60\cdot10=88{,}300{,}800{,}000\approx87{,}178{,}291{,}200=14!$$ but I don't see any obvious way to get from $6$ to $14$.

Comment: BTW, are you the Kelly Heaton of https://www.kellyheatonstudio.com ? (I'll delete the inquiry if you're not.)

Comment: @barrycipra thank you. The answer is probably in his combination of those 6 elements -- he is describing how to build an intelligent robot using analog electronic components. I wish he had given more explanation of the connections between the elements. It seems to me that when six elements are connected by analog components (capable of oscillating in a continuous waveform), the permutations of the system would be infinite. Especially if those six elements are capable to change each other, such as the increase or reduction of electrical charge, as happens in the human brain.

Comment: @barrycipra yes

Comment: Perhaps someone at https://ai.stackexchange.com might have a better idea what Walter's notations mean. (I would use a "history" tag there.)

Comment: @barrycipra Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: If you haven't already come across it, it might be worth taking a look at a paper on the legacy of Grey Walter, downloadable at https://www.researchgate.net/publication/9025611_Exploration_and_high_adventure_The_legacy_of_Grey_Walter -- especially an excerpt, on page 2097, from Walter's book *The Living Brain*. The paper also has some lovely photos from Walter's Elsie/Elmer experiments that would have done Man Ray proud.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115569/discussion-between-kelly-heaton-and-barry-cipra).

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what Walter is describing concretely in detail, but it sounds vaguely like he is counting the number of possible states a simple "nervous system" composed of $6$ elements can be in, whatever that means (when he talks about "variety of experience" a few sentences later). Here's a count that comes close to his number: among $6$ elements there are ${6 \choose 2} = 15$ pairwise connections, and if we roughly follow his sentence about "six modes" (which I don't understand) let's say that each of these pairwise connections can be in one of $5$ possible states: no connection, a connection $A \to B$, a connection $B \to A$, a connection both ways, and whatever "$A + B$" means. This gives

$$5^{15} \approx 3 \times 10^{10}$$

possible states. His "a tenth of a second for $280$ years" number is $8.8 \times 10^{10}$ so this gets within a factor of $3$. This isn't quite close enough that I can claim that it's what he's talking about, though.

Comment: that's a great explanation, thank you!